# Can Twilio subaccounts use main account active numbers and verified caller IDs?

Tags: twilio

We have created a subaccount in Twilio to allow us to better keep track of a specific product's usage and before we take the leap, I want to know if there is anything special that needs to be done in regards to the Active numbers and Verified Caller IDs.

We have quite a number of Active phone numbers in the Main account that this product uses for accepting incoming voice calls through a webhook and I am wondering if we will need to somehow migrate these numbers and their respective Voice configuration from the Main account into the subaccount.

We also currently use the Twilio main account through the Outgoing API to send SMS messages and want make sure there isn't anything special that will need to get done (other than changing the Twilio Account SID and Auth Token to the new subaccount values).

Thanks!
Lawrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent account doesn't share the active numbers with subaccounts, so you will need to migrate the numbers that you want to use on subaccount from the parent account.

Comment: Is this migration something that we can do through our Twilio login or is it something we need to coordinate with Twilio support on?

Comment: looks like it can be done via API https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360038163473-Move-Phone-Numbers-Between-Twilio-Accounts-and-their-Subaccounts